# Find the unit price of each item which was paid as whole

Tags: problem-solving, word-problem

I am trying to help my daughter in her math and there is this question I can't quite get my head around, The sum is:

Three friends go into a book shop. Salma buys a cook book and a novel, she pays \$ 20.75. Isla buys the same novel and a dictionary. Her bill comes to \$ 26.65. Josh buys a cook book and a Dictionary and pays \$ 30.90.

What is the price of each book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Setting $C=$ price of cook book; $N=$price of novel and $D=$price of dictionary, we get the equations
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{crccc}
C& + N & & = &20.75\\
& N & + D & = & 26.65 \\
C &&+D &=& 30.90
\end{array}
\right.
$$
This is fairly easy to solve. Adding the first and last equations together, we obtain
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{crccc}
2C& + N & +D & = &51.65\\
& N & + D & = & 26.65 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
From which we can easily see (by subtracting the equations from each other) that 
$$
2C = 25.00 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad C = 12.50
$$
now we can plug in this value to the original last equation, and we obtain $D = 30.90 - 12.50 = 18.40$. Similarly, plugging this result in the second equation of the original set, we get $N=26.65 - 18.40 = 8.25$

The final answers are therefore
$$
C = 12.50 \qquad N = 8.25 \qquad D = 18.40
$$

Comment: Actually I don't know how to work out the answer. Also can you advise where I can find similar sums online?

Comment: About finding similar stuff online: I don't have any recommendations right now, but I would advise googling "solving systems of linear equations".

Comment: Matti P. Thank you so much for the prompt response, more than the answer I was keen to know about the process to achieving the answer. This helps a great deal. Gold bless.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to put it in a way, so you may explain it to your daughter.

Let's denote $C$ price for cook book, $N$ novel, $D$ dictionary.

So you have
$C + N = 20.75$, $N + D = 20.65$ and $C + D = 30.90$.
Now the cost of buying a cook book and selling a dictionary $ C - D = C + N - (N + D)  = 20.75 -20.65 = 0.10$. And finally buying two cookbooks: $2C = 2C - D + D = C + D + (C - D) = 30.90 + 0.10 = 31.00$. So $C = 15.50$. The rest should by easy.